# Subcaption Package is producing errors

Tags: subcaption

I am working on a document which uses this `\subcaptionbox` from the package `subcaption`. Recently I updated MikTeX and now every single subfigure is producing four errors (I use TexStudio). Which option is the best?:

1. Get the previous version of MikTeX
2. Use another package with similar results
3. Set a configuration to ignore these errors
4. Use another TeX editor (I'm almost sure the errors are coming from the pdfLaTeX but maybe it is worth trying)

Here it is the MWE in which I copied the example directly from the subcaption Docs:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{A cat\label{cat}}
    {\includegraphics{cat}}
    \subcaptionbox{An elephant\label{elephant}}
    {\includegraphics{elephant}}
    \caption{Two animals}\label{animals}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The errors are the following:

```
Argument of \caption@@@withoptargs has an extra }. {\includegraphics{cat}}
Paragraph ended before \caption@@@withoptargs was complete. {\includegraphics{cat}}
Argument of \caption@@@withoptargs has an extra }. {\includegraphics{cat}}
Paragraph ended before \caption@@@withoptargs was complete. {\includegraphics{cat}}
```

All these errors for line 9. And the same errors for line 11. The pdf was created as intended but I can not see it in the TexStudio viewer due to the errors. I cannot work like that.

This is one of the figures I'm using in my document. I cannot include all the code here, because the preamble is masive. But maybe someone can suggest other package in which i can achieve the same result.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{ skip=-6cm, margin={-0.5cm,0cm}, singlelinecheck=off}
    \subcaptionbox{\label{yme}}
    {\input{img/yshape.tex}}
    \hspace{1cm}
    \subcaptionbox{\label{yfo}}
    {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{ysh}}
    \captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}
    \caption{
        Dispositivo de selecci\'on en forma de "Y".
        \subref{yme} Medidas,
        \subref{yfo} con la arena y el agua
    }
    \label{f.y}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: this is known and will be corrected soon. Load `\usepackage{nameref}` (hyperref if you want links) for now to avoid the error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you! Is There a changelog page I can follow? In the CTAN website I can just see the date of the last release. (Sorry maybe it is an obvius question, I'm a noob in LaTeX)

Comment: there is an issue here https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/167. It is already closed, the maintainer must only sent to ctan and then miktex must pick it up. But loading nameref is fine, it won't do harm.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!